# SQLPlus: Execute SQL scripts located on database server machine

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

Is there a possibility to execute an SQL script that is located on the database server using SQLPlus?

For example, if I execute `@@?/rdbms/admin/awrrpti.sql` the SQL file located on the client machine is used (if existent). Can I tell SQLPlus to look the script up on the server itself (without SSHing into the remote machine)?

Comment: Why not just connect to the location that holds the scripts and run them that way? You wouldn't need to ssh in.

Comment: @NasirRiley: I'm not quite sure what you mean by "why not just connect to the location" - how can I achieve that? I'm already connected to the database server, but it seems like only local files are accessed by using @@?

Comment: What operating system are you using for SQLPlus?

Comment: @NasirRiley: I'm using a Linux OS and I am trying to automate this on a Jenkins slave

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: no, you cannot.

sqlplus is a client application, it has no way to access the server's filesystem.